# Vue js. Перебор

Tags: vue.js

```
<modal :width="1000" :height="100" name="list-programs">
    <select name="" id="program" class="form-control" @change="onAddProgram()">
        <option>...</option>
        <option v-for="item, index in programlist" v-if="item" :value="index">{{ item.print_code + ' - ' + item.title }}</option>
    </select>
</modal>

<table class="table dataTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Программа</th>
        <th>Сумма по программе</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in data" @click="onSelectedProgram(index)" :class="{'active-tr': selectedProgramIndex === index}" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <td>{{ programlist[index].print_code + " - " + programlist[index].title  }}</td>
        <td>{{ programlist[index].summa }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

onAddProgram() {
    let index = $("#program option:selected").val();
    this.data[index] = []
    this.hide('list-programs')
    console.log(this.data)
},
```

При добавлении не работает перебор внутри таблицы.

Для дальнейшего кода мне надо чтобы индексы элементов `programlist` был индексов массива `data`

Comment: придется решить другим способом

Answer (score 0):

Для перебора массива лучше использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
<controll v-for="row in rows"
                  v-bind:key="row.id"
                  v-bind:id="row.id"
                  v-bind:title="row.title"
                  v-bind:subtitle="row.subtitle">
</controll>
```

Попробуйте исправить

```
   <tr v-for="(item, index) in data" @click="onSelectedProgram(index)" :class="{'active-tr': selectedProgramIndex === index}" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <td>{{ programlist[index].print_code + " - " + programlist[index].title  }}</td>
        <td>{{ programlist[index].summa }}</td>
    </tr>
```

на

```
  <tr v-for="item in data" @click="onSelectedProgram(index)" :class="{'active-tr': selectedProgramIndex === index}" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <td>{{ item.print_code + " - " + item.title  }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.summa }}</td>
    </tr>
```